# When I draw on the image, the image enlarges

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, drawing

`imageView` is the photo. I created a copy of the photo called `tempImageView` and I tried to draw on the `tempImageView`. However, when I try to draw `tempImageView`, it enlarges to fill the entire screen.

```
func createTempImageView(){
    tempImageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.image!.size.width, height: imageView.image!.size.height))
    tempImageView.center = CGPoint(x: imageView.center.x, y: imageView.center.y)
    view.insertSubview(tempImageView, aboveSubview: imageView)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I set `imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit`, the image on screen has a smaller width and height than the original image. However, the `imageView.image!.size.width` and `imageView.image!.size.height` refers the original image. Therefore, when I tried to draw on the tempImageView, the image enlarged because tempImageView refers to the original image, which is much larger than the image on screen.

To get the dimensions of the image on screen and to stop the image from enlarging, I did this:

```
func createTempImageView(){
    let widthRatio = imageView.bounds.size.width / imageView.image!.size.width
    let heightRatio = imageView.bounds.size.height / imageView.image!.size.height
    let scale = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
    let imageWidth = scale * imageView.image!.size.width
    let imageHeight = scale * imageView.image!.size.height

    tempImageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))
    tempImageView.center = CGPoint(x: imageView.center.x, y: imageView.center.y)
    tempImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    view.insertSubview(tempImageView, aboveSubview: imageView)
}
```